# Python script failed but Robot framework says Passed

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to run python script by using OperatingSystem Library but when I execute the test, the python script fails but in Robot framework shows Passed

In Robot Framework:

```
*** Settings ***
Library        OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***

Executing Python 
    ${result}=    Run    python3 Main.py --config ./config3220.ini 
    Log To Console    ${result}
```

Console:

```
ERROR:root:SerialClient could not be opened. Check connection
ERROR:root:Error at opening reference: Reference could not be opened. Check connection
Executing Python                                                      | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example                                                               | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
```

Is there any way to test if the script is working correctly?

My solution was to add this line:

```
Should Not Contain    ${result}    Error
```

but its a short-term solution

If I debug the python script without RF, I got this message
[see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOzxO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for the run keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Run) says:

> **The execution status of the command is not checked by this keyword**, and it must be done separately based on the returned output.

However, there is another advice in the above documentation:

> If the execution return code is needed, either [Run And Return RC](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Run%20And%20Return%20Rc) or [Run And Return RC And Output](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Run%20And%20Return%20Rc%20And%20Output) can be used.

You need to return a value from your `Main.py` for this to work, of course.